# How to pass a list of keys to FirebaseRecylerAdapter instead of Query/DatabaseReference?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Going through whole firebase data I have made list of keys whose content meets my conditions, now I want to show contents under these keys in a RecyclerView of a different activity. Is it possible with [FirebaseRecyclerAdapter](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java)

Please suggest alternate ways to do this too

Comment: Its not clear what you want here, because you can pass Query as well as items and also keys, what else you want?

Comment: Sorry, the link was wrong. Edited the quesion